# Solve for $x$ ,$\frac{(1+2^x-2)\cdot x}{2}=6$

Tags: calculus

$\frac{(1+2^x-2)\cdot x}{2}=6$

So far I did:

$$\frac{(1+2^x-2)\cdot x}{2}=6 \Leftrightarrow \frac{(2^x-1)\cdot x}{2} = 6 \Leftrightarrow \frac{2^x\cdot x -x}{2}=6 \Leftrightarrow 2^x\cdot x -x = 12 \Leftrightarrow ???$$

What do I do next?

Comment: Is $x$ integer or real.

Comment: just notice that $2^x \cdot x-x$ is increasing when $x>0$ and decreasing when $x<0$ and both cases have a transcendental solution.

Comment: Do you require anything about $x$? For real $x$ standard calculus techniques can be used to show there are exactly two solutions.

Comment: do you want to specifically find x

Comment: @Fimpellizieri The solution should be $\approx$ 2.52.

Comment: @superbjhon Yes

Comment: @AbdallahHammam It's real

Comment: This is *almost* in a form where we can apply the Lambert W Function.  So far as I am aware, there are no analytical representations for the solution.

Comment: i can give you a link

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B(1%2B2%5Ex-2)x%7D%2F2%3D6

Comment: @superbjhon To WolframAlpha? I have already tried there. I know the solution, what I really want to know is the steps I am missing in my attempt

Comment: i will try my best to solve  it

Comment: @superbjhon Okay, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer so much as it is an overview of potential methods of solution.

Your best bet is to implement newton's method.  The solution, $x^*$ is a root of the function $r(x) = x2^x-x-12$.  Thus, using newton's method

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{r(x_n)}{r'(x_n)} $$

Iterate until you reach a desired level of accuracy (i.e when $\lvert x_n - x_{n+1} \rvert < \epsilon$ for pre determined epsilon).

Another, perhaps more interesting, avenue is to try and use the Lambert W function.

Rewrite the problem as

$$ \ln(2)x\left( \exp\left( x\ln(2) \right) -1 \right) = 12 \ln(2) $$

If that -1 were not there, then the solution is straight forward application of the Lambert W Function.  There may be ways to solve this with the Lambert W Function to which I am oblivious.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find an explicit solution for this equation, but you can 
get an approximation. Set
$$
f(x)=6-\frac{x(2^x-1)}{2}.
$$
Clearly, $f(x)$ is continuous. Note that 
$$
f(\frac{5}2)=\frac{29}{4}-5\sqrt{2}>0
$$
$$
f(\frac{11}4)=\frac{59}{8}-\frac{11}{\sqrt[4]{2}}<0
$$
Hence, there exist $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$, where $x_0\in[\frac{5}2,\frac{11}4]$, that is 
$x_0\in[2.5,2.75]$.